# Storing data from Input fields into database React-Express-Postgress

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm trying to make a web app which lets you enter it once via email which is a simple input field with a button for submission. After entering the email the user will either be allowed in if the email has never been entered before or will be denied access if the email has been used previously.
 As I'm new to both fullstack and ReactJS I was wondering what would be the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Sounds like a security risk to me. At the very least, you'd want to send an email verification code for the user to enter in your site for access. This would prove user is in control of the email address.

Comment: The site wont be published and purely for personal use I'll take care of security later on.